# Jenkins 2.121.1 use TLS 1.0

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins

For legacy reasons I have to use TLS 1.0 with Jenkins. I have just downloaded the setup and installed.

How do I configure Jenkins to use TLS 1.0 instead of the default TLS 1.2?

Inside my Jenkins.xml I have this

```
<executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

There are 2 issues here:

1) Is this the correct way?

2) How do I verify which TLS is being used?

Comment: httpPort=8080 are you sure of that ? We usually see 8443 instead.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: I am on http and not https therefore it is 8080

Comment: I don't know what you are doing exactly, but if you are talking to an SSL enabled server the communication will be in https, not http.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1` is unsure, it might depend on the Java implementation and version as stated in the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) :

> This property is currently used by the JSSE implementation, but it is
>   not guaranteed to be examined and used by other implementations.

The same guide would suggest to use `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1` if your Java is recent enough.

To check, you can add another property to see what's really happening (`-Djavax.net.debug=all`), or do a network capture and look at the ClientHello.

Comment: I can do a network capture using Fiddler. However what do you mea by ClientHello?

Comment: I mean the ClientHello record as defined in RFC 2246. Anyway, your capture will show you this.